# How to pass two images picked from UIImagePickerController to another ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I have two images in one view controller which have been picked with `UIImagePickerController`:

`ChoosePhotosViewController.h`

```
@interface PickPhotosViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *pickedImage1; // image 1
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImag8eView *pickedImage2; // image 2

- (IBAction)pickImage1:(id)sender; // button that picks up the first image
- (IBAction)pickImage2:(id)sender; // button that picks up the seconds image
- (IBAction)nextButton:(id)sender;
```

in implementation file - `ChoosePhotosViewController.m`

```
@implementation PickPhotosViewController
@synthesize pickedImage1, pickedImage2;
```

for each button I wrote a code which invokes action sheet with a list of actions:

```
-(IBAction)pickImage1:(id)sender {
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:CurrentImageCategoryImage1 forKey:@"currentImageCategory"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Choose image one" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Choose existing photo", @"Take new photo", nil];
[actionSheet showInView:self.view];
}
```

There are two actions - take photo from camera air upload from library:

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
if (buttonIndex == 0) {
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
else if (buttonIndex == 1) {
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
}
```

The similar algorithm for the second button. Then in `UIImagePickerController` method I wrote;

```
-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary*)info { 

UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];    

if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"currentImageCategory"] ==CurrentImageCategoryImage1)
    {
    self.pickedImage1.image = chosenImage;
    }
else if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"currentImageCategory"] ==CurrentImageCategoryImage2)
    {
    self.pickedImage2.image = chosenImage;
    }
}
```

Then I need to display these two images in the next viewController when I click button “next”. I work with storyboards, that is why I wrote `prepareForSegue` method:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@“next"]) {
    TypeTextViewController *transferedImage = [segue destinationViewController];
    transferedImage.imageWithText1 = pickedImage1;
    }   
}
```

where `imageWithText1` is a `UIImageView` and declared in `TypeTextViewController.h`, but When I click button images don’t appear in the `TypeTextViewController`.

Where is a problem?

Comment: Your quotation mark incorrect, Put @"next". are you check if block working or not?

Comment: In the code mark is ok, maybe when I was typing to StackOverFlow I did a mistake. Code is working

Answer (score 1):

You want to create **NSMutableArray** and then this two **Images add** into this Array.And then you have to pass this NSMutableArray to Another View Controller.

Hope this is helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can pass a UIImageView from one VC to another VC. I think we can only pass UIImage and not UIImageView. Try this.. But im not sure.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 
{
  if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@“next"]) 
  {
  TypeTextViewController *transferedImage = [segue destinationViewController];
  transferedImage.imageWithText1.image = pickedImage1.image;
  }   

}
```

Comment: it doesn't work. Doest it mean that I should create UIImage property in the second VC to pass image?

Answer (score 0):

// pass Image one view to other view:

```
      - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

{

```
   UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^
 {
     color_ViewController*secondview=[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil]instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"color_ViewController"];
      secondview.b_image=image;
      [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults ]setInteger:1 forKey:@"123"];
       [[self navigationController] pushViewController:secondview animated:YES];
 }];
     }
```